# categories on upload php upload page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello I'm working on a project that has an upload page and in the background it uploads the pictures in `dir /uploads/` and saves it to the `user_images` table (the url) in my datebase.

So, I want to have a gallery with categories, but when they upload I need something like a `dropdown menu` where they choose something like cars, houses, etc.

In my gallery I need to show the categories. I'm thinking like all the categories with id's.

When I submit, the table will be id and image_link, and in the gallery page I specify in this div that I want the images with `id=x`.

Can someone help me with this? i'd be really happy! ps: sorry for my bad english

edit: i need it in with pdo Thanks again!

upload.php;

```
    <center><form action="galleryupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select image to upload:
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
        </form></center>
</div>
```

galleryupload.php;

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) && $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] != "") {
} else {
    header('location:index.php');
}
?>
<body style="background-color: lightgray"></body>
<center><img src="../images/x.png"></center>

<?php
include "db.php";
$target_file2 = "random-dir/";
$target_dir = "random-dir/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file3 = $target_file2 .$target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<h1><center>File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . "." ."</center></h1>";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<h1><center>File is not an image.</center></h1>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center>Sorry, file already exists.</center></h1>";
    echo "<h1><a href = gallery-edit.php>Go back </a></h1>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center>Sorry, your file is too large.</center></h1>";
    echo "<h1><a href = gallery-edit.php>Go back </a></h1>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</center></h1>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</center></h1>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<h1><center><a href = gallery-edit.php>Go back </a></center></h1>";


} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "<h1><center>The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.</center></h1>";
        echo " <meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5;url=gallery-edit.php\" />";
        echo "<center><h1>You Will be redicted to user gallery in 5 seconds...</h1></center>";
        echo "<center><h1>If your browser doesn't support redict please<a href=gallery-edit.php> click here </h1></a></center>";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_image (image_link) VALUES (:image_link)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(':image_link', $target_file3);

        $result = $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<center>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</center>";
        echo " <center><a href = gallery-edit.php>Go back </a></center>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What isn't working as expected?  What do you need help with?

Comment: I would add a column like 'category_id' for the category id's to the table 'user_image' and save the selected category in there. Then you can load all images by category (SELECT image_link FROM user_image WHERE category_id=123) where 123 is the id of the category you want to show. Is this what you are looking for?